# Meteor server inside browser: feasibility?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Is it technically feasible to run the Meteor server-side stuff inside a browser tab?

What technical limitations of the browser environment would absolutely eliminate this possibility?

To be clear, yes, I am asking what you think I'm asking -- NodeJS in a tab with Meteor on top! :)

Comment: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What characteristics of Meteor would you like to run in your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I'll have a go.

> Is it technically feasible?

What would you need to make this happen?

- node.js in the browser. [It exists, kind of.](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)
- A database backend. You'd need MongoDB, also in the browser. I bet you could implement something on top of HTML5 LocalStorage, but it'd be a slog. Add to that the fact that Meteor doesn't currently support anything but MongoDB, and you're in for a world of hurt.
- The magical Meteoric "glue" that makes it all work together -- in other words, the reason you're using Meteor in the first place.

If what you're really asking is

> Is it a good idea?

The answer is almost certainly no.

I know several of the people who work at Meteor. This, ah, isn't on their [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/hjBDflxp/meteor-roadmap).

That said, if you could hack it together, give them a call -- especially if you happen to be looking for a job! :)

Comment: ha, no I'm not asking if it's a good idea! bad ideas are ok with me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about how to prototype and run a Meteor app without having to install anything on your machine, you certainly aren't the first person with this idea. It's already been done:

> https://www.discovermeteor.com/2013/10/04/meteor-nitrous/

In short, a hosted development platform for Meteor is probably superior to trying to cram it all in a browser anyway.